# Did David Hume ever express the concept of "compresence" personally?

Tags: hume, perception

In David Hume's "A Treatise of Human Nature", Hume introduces the concept of "bundle theory". Bundle theory is the idea that the identity of objects (or selves) is defined by bundles of perceptions. (properties, tropes or universals)

Many different resources suggest that one of the major objections to bundle theory is that Hume fails to account for the "compresence" of those bundles of perceptions... what holds together those properties? The complaint is that Hume doesn't describe how compresence works.

However, I can't find anywhere in Hume's writings where he suggests that compresence is even necessary. As far as I can tell, this is an idea added by substance theorists who suggest that it is the substance of an object that holds the properties of the object together. That's fine if it is, but it doesn't answer the question of whether or not *David Hume* thought that these properties needed to be held together.

Are people merely assuming that Hume accidentally skipped this part, or does Hume describe the idea of compresence somewhere and I can't find it? I don't care if he uses the actual word "compresence", I just want to know if he describes the idea. **I don't want to quote Hume as "not mentioning compresence" if I'm just an idiot who can't find the reference to save my life.**

Comment: Hume did not express himself in terms of second order relations, this parlance came later and the term "compresence" is Russell's (and there are several other names used). But it was introduced by bundle theorists themselves, not by substance theorists, because it is just a paraphrase of talking about "bundles". Whether we call it "bundling relation" or "compresence", without bundling of properties there will be no bundles to talk about. Substance theorists' objection is that it is a quaint free floating relation unattached to anything, it is a version of incredulous stare.

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot.